# Using HTML5 input "date" in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

HTML5 seems to have new input types like "date" available for many current browser, if I put:

```
    Birthday: <input type="date" id="bday", name="bday"/>
```

it pops up quite good date picker on Chrome! I could post selected date to server with help of javascript:

```
        updateDate: function() {
        var date = $('#bday').val();
        var params = { date: date };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/HelloWorld/updateDateJson',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) { $('#timeServer2').text(result); }
            //error: function () { $('#ErrorSelfService').text("Ajax error"); }
        });
```

But then can I use it in a native asp.net mvc3 way using view model and partial view. Some clarification will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use it in the same way as it is just posted as a normal string value.

Note though that other browsers may not support this (IE 9 for ex doesnt) so is still recommend just using the jQuery UI date picker control with a jquery mask plugin for MM/dd/yyyy input format (or whatever your supported cultures are for date format)